Stop systemd service on run level change
I need to stop a service when the run-level changes from graphical target (5) to mulit-user target (3). And then start it again when the run-level changes back to graphical target. But, I'm coming up empty trying to find a way to do that. Does anyone know if this is possible with systemd?
